# Element not visible even id present for the element

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, manual-testing, selenium2

[image]

I want to check one element, with help of that element id, prepared selenium web driver script, when will click on that ui element it will open another hided section on same window, but getting error "Element not visible"
Before few days it was working with same script using "id" locator.
I am learning automation and don't understand it was working before and now why getting this error. Please let me know if anyone faces this issue and have a solution to resolve it.

The HTML:

```
<h3 id="hubH3-524" title="pretest" ng-click="toggleSelection('hubH3-524','pretest',1)" role="button" tabindex="0" style="font-size: 9px; padding: 9px 0px 2px;">pretest</h3>
```

My code:

```
   public class Simpletest {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     try {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\Selenium\\seleniumchromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://abc.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("enter email");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("enter password");
        driver.findElements(By.className("abcGenericButton")).get(2).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000); 
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 1000).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.id("hubH3-3"))));
        //driver.findElement(By.id("hubH3-3")).click(); 
        driver.findElement(By.id("detailBtn")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("btnSettingsHub")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("hubDescription")).click();
        WebElement hubDescription = driver.findElement(By.id("hubDescription"));
        hubDescription.sendKeys("This is testing hub");
       } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
 }        
 }
```

Comment: Can you please share code and html page ?

Comment: More details would help us to encounter problem easily

Comment: When user click on this element "Pretest", right side section "details" tab get display on same window. that pretest having id. so i used that id but getting error "no such element: Unable to locate element"

driver.findElement(By.id("hubH3-3")).click();

Comment: Please share HTML code screenshot. Not HTML page.

Comment: Its not working yet, getting error "no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"hubH3-3"}"

Comment: Can you post the URL, Or add some html code in your question

Comment: <h3 id="hubH3-524" title="pretest" ng-click="toggleSelection('hubH3-524','pretest',1)" role="button" tabindex="0" style="font-size: 9px; padding: 9px 0px 2px;">pretest</h3>

This is the html code which i get behind "pretest" element, which i used.
Following are my web driver code

Comment: I have given answer. Please check it. If it resolve your issue, kindly mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **As per your commented HTML code , This should be solution.**

```
 Thread.sleep(1000); 
 new WebDriverWait(driver, 1000).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(By.xpath("//h3[contains(@id,'hubH3')]")));
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[contains(@id,'hubH3')]")).click();
```

### **Problem Statement :**

- Here `id` attribute is dynamic. So every time page gets load , it changing its count.

### **Solution :**

- So use `contains` or `starts-with` function in xpath. (Only xpath locator provides it.)

> **Note : I would suggest to wait for page load and then click.**

Comment: Please comment here if any issues are there.

Comment: I update bit things in code provided by you and its working. Thanks Sager

Comment: @NilamNikam  Please accept my answer as true if my answer able to solve issue.